# Selection css tag without id

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, selection

I need help with setting up a wordpress menu.
I made my html css but when I go under wordpress and when I use the wp_nav_menu () function I lose my specific id on `<a>` tags, Wordpress automatically generates new `<li> <a>`.
How can I select them from the class "menu_word" please?

```
        <ul class="menu_word">
          <li><a id="home" href="#">Tilte1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tilte2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tilte3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tilte4</a></li>
          <li><a id="sem" href="#">Tilte4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tilte5</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go

```css
body .menu_word >li:nth-child(1)> a{ /*Title1 on pos 1 (specific for first level of menu)*/
  border:1px solid red;
}

body .menu_word >li:nth-child(2)> a{ /*Title2 on pos 2 (specific for first level of menu)*/
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
        <ul class="menu_word">
          <li><a id="home" href="#">Tilte1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tilte2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tilte3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tilte4</a></li>
          <li><a id="sem" href="#">Tilte4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tilte5</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a class and target that?

If not, this will work, although its pretty brittle.  It'll become more robust if you can add a class to the UL, but if you can add a class, you may as well add it to the `<a>` tag, or the `<li>` tag.

```
body > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, I also find a solution that I share if it can help.

```
   <ul class="menu_word">
          <li><a id="home" href="home">Tilte1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tilte2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tilte3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tilte4</a></li>
          <li><a id="sem" href="sem">Tilte4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tilte5</a></li>
        </ul>

a[href*="home"]{
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

a[href*="sem"]{
    text-transform: capitalize;
 }
```